# String/Case programing error

Tags: java, string, if-statement, case

I was able to get invalid major when I put a letter that is not listed major, but if I put t2, I would only get invalid major and not (invalid major, sophomore). Can someone detect the code and tell me where I went wrong.

---

```
    // Enter two characters

    System.out.print("Enter two characters: ");
    String status = in.next();

    char major = Character.toUpperCase(status.charAt(0));
    char year = status.charAt(1);

    String courseName = "";
    String yearName = "";

    // majors

    if (major == 'B' || major == 'I' || major == 'C')
    {
        switch(major)
        {
            case 'B':
                courseName = "Biology"; break;
            case 'C':
                courseName = "Computer Science"; break;
            case 'I':
                courseName = "Information Technology"; break;

            default:System.out.println("Invaild major"); break;
        }

        // year

        switch(year)
        {
            case '1':
                yearName = "Freshman"; break;
            case '2':
                yearName = "Sophmore"; break;
            case '3':
                yearName = "Junior"; break;
            case '4':
                yearName = "Senior"; break;

            default: System.out.println("Invalid year status"); break;
        }

        System.out.printf("%s %s%n", courseName, yearName);
    }
    else{
        System.out.printf("Invalid input.%n"); 
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Get rid of `if (major == 'B' || major == 'I' || major == 'C')` otherwise you'll never run your `switch` statements when you enter `T1`.

Comment: When I put B5 i was able to get invalid year and biology but when i put T1 all I get is invalid input. Help!

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem sorry, i was testing my code and fixing it and then after i commented it, your answer appeared. It seems like your solution solved the problem! thank you so much!!

Comment: No problem.  Good luck with your ongoing learning.

Comment: Please don't destroy your question after it is answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Remove:

```
if (major == 'B' || major == 'I' || major == 'C')
{
```

and

```
 else{
    System.out.printf("Invalid input.%n"); 
}
```

Your 'if statement' is preventing you from getting the desired output.